# Android language parsing difficulties

Tags: android

In my android app I implemented `asynctask` to check server responses. It was working fine until the language problem. I am sending user google `email id` and `user name` to server for authentication purpose.

But server is sending errors when the user name is other than `English`.

Here is my code . . .

```
HttpAsyncTaskCheckAuth checkAuth = new HttpAsyncTaskCheckAuth(SignUpActivity.this);
                checkAuth.execute("http://www.server_address.com//auth/login?email=" +
                        email +
                        "&name=" + name +
                        "&logged_in=" + "true");
```

This is working fine if I enter name which is `English`. When user enter name which is not English, the server does not execute successfully.

Here is the error message I got in LogCat

```
09-26 16:09:34.567 3838-3838/package_name W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value Traceback of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
09-26 16:09:34.567 3838-3838/package_name W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
09-26 16:09:34.567 3838-3838/package_name W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
09-26 16:09:34.567 3838-3838/package_name W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
09-26 16:09:34.567 3838-3838/package_name W/System.err:     at package_name.asyncTask.HttpAsyncTaskCheckAuth.onPostExecute(HttpAsyncTaskCheckAuth.java:53)
09-26 16:09:34.567 3838-3838/package_name W/System.err:     at package_name.asyncTask.HttpAsyncTaskCheckAuth.onPostExecute(HttpAsyncTaskCheckAuth.java:18)
09-26 16:09:34.567 3838-3838/package_name W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
09-26 16:09:34.567 3838-3838/package_name W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-26 16:09:34.567 3838-3838/package_name W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
09-26 16:09:34.567 3838-3838/package_name W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-26 16:09:34.567 3838-3838/package_name W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
09-26 16:09:34.567 3838-3838/package_name W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6856)
09-26 16:09:34.567 3838-3838/package_name W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-26 16:09:34.567 3838-3838/package_name W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-26 16:09:34.567 3838-3838/package_name W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
09-26 16:09:34.567 3838-3838/package_name W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

How can I convert name in a formate which will be executed successfully?

I tried the following methods but those did not worked for me

```
URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8").replaceAll(" ","%20")
```

and

```
URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8").replaceAll(" ","%20")
```

When I checked the same URL on `Postman` an extension in Chrome, I got the following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1401, in _stack_context_handle_exception
    raise_exc_info((type, value, traceback))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 314, in wrapped
    ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1613, in future_complete
    f.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 282, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "startup.py", line 15884, in get
    print user["name"]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Please suggest me possible ways to solve this issue.

Comment: what error server send when you send name in other that English ?

Comment: @BhawnaRaheja I got this error org.json.JSONException: Value Traceback of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: Update the question the with the exact error you get.

Comment: did you try accessing the URL from a web browser?

Comment: @user1506104 yes I tried. Please see the updated question. There I added the error too.

Comment: 404 error means your web resource cannot be found.

Comment: @user1506104 by mistake I added the wrong error message. I updated the error message. Please check again.

Comment: It's all in the message: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128)`. It means it's server problem, not yours. It uses ASCII, hence few characters are available. See Ascii table here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: the problem is with your server, not the client. the error is: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters" an ASCII coded can handle english letters only, you need to change how the server parse names.

Comment: @marmor But a webpage is accessing the same api and it is working fine.

Comment: `name` and `email` are both encoded properly?

Comment: @anuradha you wrote that trying with Postman generated the same error response, so it doesn't sounds like a client issue. Which webpage is working fine? a page you control?

Comment: I converted the string to unicode and send it to server using restclint and it is working. Now I need to send the unicode from my android code.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using `URLEncoder` instead of `URLDecoder`. Your `URL` should be **encoded**, not **decoded** when accessing web sources.

> All other characters are unsafe and are first converted into one or
>   more bytes using some encoding scheme. Then each byte is represented
>   by the 3-character string "%xy", where xy is the two-digit hexadecimal
>   representation of the byte. The recommended encoding scheme to use is
>   UTF-8. However, for compatibility reasons, if an encoding is not
>   specified, then the default encoding of the platform is used.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: I tried both URLEncoder and URLDecoder. But none of these worked.

Comment: can you share here how you did the encoding?

Comment: URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8").replaceAll(" ","%20")

Comment: remove the `replaceAll("","%20")`. The URLEncoder does this automatically for you.

Comment: no it does not replace spaces with %20. It replaces space with +

Comment: whatever you are trying to replace, do not do it. URLEncode does it for you.

Comment: ok I tested without replaceAll("","%20"), but still I got the same error.