# sending multiple types of languages to server in android

Tags: android

I implemented google authentication in my android app. I need to send gmail id, username to my server for account authentication. Everything was working fine until I tried to login with a Bengali username.

Here is my code to access sever

```
HttpAsyncTaskCheckAuth checkAuth = new HttpAsyncTaskCheckAuth(SignUpActivity.this);
                checkAuth.execute("http://www.server_address.com//auth/login?email=" +
                        email +
                        "&name=" + name +
                        "&logged_in=" + "true");
```

Here I an getting email and name from google plus authentication in android. How can I solve this language issue? Do I need to parse the name(user name) in any international formate so that the server can proceed with it?

Please suggest me some solutions to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Please, check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android) can solve your issues. Most servers expect UTF-8 encoded query. And most if not all libraries will convert them. It is possible that a `MalformedURLException` or something else is being triggered locally (and thus we need the Logcat), or the server is simply ignoring your request, replying some `HTTP 500` response (and thus we would need the server logs).

Comment: This is ***EXACTLY*** the same problem as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699758/android-language-parsing-difficulties/39700660?noredirect=1#comment66699767_39700660. This question will most likely be tagged as ***DUPLICATE***. If your question does not receive enough attention, you can use the ***Bounty*** feature after few days.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the query parameter values. There are various ways of doing that, one of them is to use the apache commons - codec library:

```
org.apache.commons.codec.net.URLCodec.encode(name);
```

See also [how to encode URL to avoid special characters in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571346/how-to-encode-url-to-avoid-special-characters-in-java)